# Knex.js method in bookshelf.js

Tags: bookshelf.js, knex.js

How to insert [a increment method](http://knexjs.org/#Builder-increment) like `bookshelf.knex('articles').increment('fetchCount', 1)` in the code below:

```
router.get('/:id', (req, res) => {
   Article.query({
      where: {id: req.params.id}
   }).fetch().then(article => {
      res.json(article)
   })
})
```

I have a table called 'articles', and I want to increment a value in a fetchCount column before it send json response.

when I use bookshelf.knex, bookshelf should be my model like Article?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bookshelf way is something like:

```
router.get('/:id', (req, res) => {
   Bookshelf.transaction(trx => {
      return Article
      .query({
         where: {id: req.params.id}
      })
      .fetch({transacting: trx})
      .then(article => {
         // handle article == null here
         return article
         .save(
            {fetchCount: 1 + article.get('fetchCount')},
            {patch: true, transacting: trx})
      })
   })
   .then(article => {
      res.json(article)
   })
})
```

The main point is having the transaction on both fetching and updating, so ensuring the value is locked and consistent until updated.